# Display 3 values in a message box with spaces between the values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to display 3 values in a `MsgBox`.

My logic statements are working, and it is picking the correct values I want - however I am unable to make my message box display 3 separate values with spaces between them.

**Problem**: I need spaces between each value, as well as the middle value is not being displayed when i run this.

```
WW = MsgBox(Application.Worksheets("Assembly1").Range("A" & Z) & Application.Worksheets("Assembly1").Range("B" & Z) & Application.Worksheets("Assembly1").Range("D" & Z), vbOKOnly, "HEY YOU HAVE SOMETHING NEW")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or if you need line breaks then use
msgbox ("A" & chr(10) & "B" & chr(10) & "C")

It will show output as:

A

B

C

Answer (score 4):

Just use `& " " &` between the values

ie

```
Z = 1
WW = MsgBox(Application.Worksheets("Assembly1").Range("A" & Z) & " " & Application.Worksheets("Assembly1").Range("B" & Z) & " " & Application.Worksheets("Assembly1").Range("D" & Z), vbOKOnly, "HEY YOU HAVE SOMETHING NEW")
```

Comment: @Pike7893 here on stackoverflow we say `Thank you` by accepting and upvoting answers (*green tick mark next to the answer*).

Answer (score 1):

for interest you can also use

```
WW = MsgBox(Join(Application.Index(Worksheets("Assembly1").Range("A" & Z, "D" & Z), 0, Array(1, 2, 4)), " "), vbOKOnly, "HEY YOU HAVE SOMETHING NEW")
```

Answer (score 1):

The messages can be displayed in seperate lines which would be clear to read.

```
WW = MsgBox(Application.Worksheets("Assembly1").Range("A" & Z) +Chr(13)+ Application.Worksh
```

Instead of spaces (& " "&) you can use either Chr(13) or vbcrlf in places where you want to introduce space. This would display the message in distinct different lines.